# как на vue вывести массив объектов

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите, как на vue вывести циклом `<li>` отзывы, надо вывести 5 отзывов с разным контентом

```
<ul>
     <li>
        <div class="img-block">
          <img src="../assets/images/user-img2.png" alt="image description">
        </div>
        <blockquote>
       <img src="../assets/images/quote.svg" alt="" class="quote">
      <p>Постоянно возникают потребности в каких-то вещах и незапланированных 
покупках. Здорово, что можно получить заем не выходя из дома через личный кабинет. Буду рекомендовать всем знакомым.</p>
      <cite><strong class="name">Александра, домохозяйка</strong> <span class="address">г.Новосибирск</span></cite>
    </blockquote>
  </li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 0):

Нужно подставить в тег

директиву v-for="item in items" вот так:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
```

Если нужен индекс - вот так:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
```

Как мне напомнили в комментах, стоит не забывать определять `:key`. Он позволяет правильно обновлять как отдельные элементы списка, так и весь список при смене списка элементов. Не используйте индекс в качестве ключа, тк при вставке/удалении элементов они меняются. Айдишники и уникальные имена годятся лучше всего!
Подробности в документации к Vue.js.

Comment: `<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">` привязку потеряли.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Просто ещё не совсем понимаю в чём её роль...

Comment: Она нужна для корректного обновления динамического контента. Но тут есть подводный камень связанный со внутренним состоянием дочерних компонентов. При использовании `index` как `:key` может возникнуть вот такой [баг](https://codesandbox.io/s/key-example-7m52b6?file=/src/App.vue). Я в свое время чуть не рехнулся, пытаясь понять почему форма ответов в списке комментариев смещается на предыдущий комментарий при добавлении вверху нового комментария (сокеты)...